# Two estimates in gradient estimate of mean curvature under volume preserving mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from 45th page of 
*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**The volume preserving mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1987.382.35), J. Reine Angew. Math. 382, 35-48 (1987). [ZBL0621.53007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.53007).

$N_2,N_1$ are constant. $M_0$ is initial manifold, and evolving under volume preserving mean curvature flow. $A$ is the second fundamental form. $H$ is mean curvature. $h(t)$ is the average of mean curvature 
$$
h(t)=\frac{\int_{M_t} H d\mu}{\int_{M_t} d\mu}
$$
And 
$$
H_T=\max_{t\in[0,T]} \max_{M_t}H
$$
Then, how to get the red line 2 and 3 ?

About getting the red line 2, I fail to deal $2N_1(1+h)|A|^2$. Because $C_6$ depends on $N_1$ and $M_0$. I feel part of $C_6$ is from $2N_1(1+h)|A|^2$.

About the red line 3, I am unfamiliar about the $\forall \eta>0$ .... Seemly, there is some  all to know but I don't know, what is it?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> [image]
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   [image]

Comment: what is $\sigma$?

Comment: By convexity you have $|A|^2 \leq H^2$.

Comment: Equation 3 is the Peter-Paul inequality (Young's inequality with $\eta$ https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality)?

Comment: @JohnMa  I think  $\sigma$ is $\delta$ in 2.1.Theorem.

Comment: @PaulBryan  Thanks, do you mean $2N_1(1+h)|A|^2\le 2N_1(1+H_T)H_T^2 \le 2CN_1H_T^3$ ? $C$ is a constant.

Comment: @lanse7pty yes, something like that.

Comment: Does that work here? Has a lower bound for H been establiahed so that $H \leq C H^3$? Or is there a little more work to be done?